# Edge browser : child div is taking more width than parent's specified width

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

We have a requirement where we have to display the prefix inside the textbox which is not editable. Please find HTML/CSS code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mxsj2ob/). Whenever we do resize of window I can see this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="uniqueNameContainer" dir="ltr">
    <div title="Publisher prefix" class="publisherPrefix">new_</div>
    <input name="uniquename" class="uniqueName" type="text" maxlength="36">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.uniqueNameContainer{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width:50%;
}

.publisherPrefix{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #888888;
}

.uniqueName{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

***Note: This code is working in all browsers except Edge.***

Issue:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not an ideal solution, but it was the best I was able to come up with.

It seems that Edge applies a default `min-width` to input elements, which is removed if `max-width`, or `min-width` is set by the CSS.

When this is recognized, fixing your page becomes as simple as adding `min-width: 0;` to the `uniqueName` class.

Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvxso0op/5/). I removed your flexbox styles on `.publisherPrefix` as they were unnecessary.

```css
.uniqueNameContainer {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
}

.publisherPrefix {
  color: #888888;
}

.uniqueName {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="uniqueNameContainer" dir="ltr">
  <div title="Publisher prefix" class="publisherPrefix">new_</div>
  <input name="uniquename" class="uniqueName" type="text" maxlength="36">
</div>
```

Comment: This is causing issue in IE now.

Comment: @alok_dida updated, working in both browsers for me now (IE didn't like flex-grow: 1, so switching back to width: 100% fixed it)

Comment: I found that. Thanks for the response.